# Formatting a Pandas dataframe (flattening multindexes)

Tags: python, pandas

I have data like this:

```
region  status  value
north   success 1
north   success 2
east    fail    2
east    open    3
```

I want to group by region and status, sum, and put together in a dataframe like so:

```
region  success fail    open
north   3       NaN     NaN
east    NaN     2       3
```

I can group and sum the data, but I don't understand how to flatten/remove/simplify the resulting MultiIndex in the code below:

```
d = {'region':['north','north','east','east'],
     'status':['success','success','fail','open'],
     'value':[1,2,2,3]}
    
df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)

df2 = df.groupby(by = ['region','status']).sum().unstack()

df2
```

That yields a MultiIndex dataframe. How can I simplify it?

```
    value
status  fail    open    success
region          
east    2.0     3.0     NaN
north   NaN     NaN     3.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for:

```
                           # Note how I select the one column.
df2 = df.groupby(['region','status'])['value'].sum().unstack()
print(df2)

# Output:

status  fail  open  success
region
east     2.0   3.0      NaN
north    NaN   NaN      3.0
```

Another method:

```
df2 = df.pivot_table(index='region', columns='status', values='value', aggfunc='sum', fill_value=0)
print(df2)

# Output:

status  fail  open  success
region
east       2     3        0
north      0     0        3
```